# Obj-c - Same data always appears in detailViewController when tapping on different tableview cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When my user taps on a cell in my tableview, it should push them to a detailViewController. This happens, but for some reason, no matter which cell my user taps, the same data appears in the detailView (it's always data from the most recently added item)? Instead of the different data that's displayed in each cell. Any idea why this is happening?

**OtherUserViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *testPets = self.userPets;

    if (tableView == self.otherPets) {


        static NSString *PetTableIdentifier = @"PetsTableViewCell";

        PetsTableViewCell *cell = (PetsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PetTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {

           cell = [[PetsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PetTableIdentifier];
        }

        NSString *petDescrip = self.petresultArray[indexPath.row][@"aboutdog"];

        cell.dogBio.text = petDescrip;


        NSString *petName = self.petresultArray[indexPath.row][@"node_title"];
        cell.petName.text = petName;

        NSString *petBreed= self.petresultArray[indexPath.row][@"breed"];
        cell.breedLabel.text = petBreed;


        NSString *secondLink = self.petresultArray[indexPath.row][@"pet_photo_path"];


        [cell.petImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

      return cell;


    } 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView == self.otherPets) {

        PetViewController *detailViewController = [[PetViewController alloc]
                                                   initWithNibName:@"PetViewController" bundle:nil];


        detailViewController.otherpetSubDetail = [self.userPets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

Comment: Your `cellForRowAt` is using `self.petresultArray` as its datasource, whereas `didSelectRowAt` is using `self.userPets` - could that be the problem?  How are those two arrays populated?

Comment: Ahh thank you - totally didn't catch that. @pbasdf